# Merge objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to convert multiple objects with same id as test to array of objects

Actual:

```
const array= [
    { "test": 1},
    { "test": 2},
 { "test": 3},
 { "test": 4},
]
```

Expected:

```
test: [1,2,3,4]
```

Can someone please help

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Do you try `array.map(e => e.test)`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the native method map (read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) like this:

```js
const array= [
  { "test": 1},
  { "test": 2},
  { "test": 3},
  { "test": 4},
];
const newArray = array.map(p => p.test);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray)); //[1,2,3,4]
```

Hope this helps.. ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map :

```
const newarray = array.map(x => x.test);
console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = {};

yourArray.forEach( ( object ) => {
  const keys = Object.keys( object );
  for ( let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
     const key = keys[ i ];
     if ( ! key in result ) { 
        result[ key ] = [];
     }
     result[key] = [...result[key], ...object[key] ];
  }
});

console.log( result );
```

In this case:

1. You need to iterate in your array
2. On each iteration you have a new object
3. From there you iterate in all the keys of that current object
4. If the key does not exists in your result create a new empty array
5. Merge the value from the result with the current value of the object.
6. Values are stored in result.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values from the object.

```js
const
    array = [{ test: 1 }, { test: 2 }, { test: 3 }, { test: 4 }],
    values = array.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  { "test": 1 },
  { "test": 2 },
  { "test": 3 },
  { "test": 4 },
  { "test1": 1 },
  { "test1": 5 },
  { "test2": 6 }
];
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
    ...acc, 
    [Object.keys(cur)[0]]: (acc[Object.keys(cur)[0]] || []).concat(Object.values(cur)[0])
}), {});

console.log( newArr );
//{ "test": [1,2,3,4], "test1": [1,5], "test2": [6] }
```